# Should custom form module in drupal be a node type?

Tags: drupal, module, crud, user-permissions, form-api

I just started to develop a new module in Drupal. The goal of the module is to capture user's data (purely CRUD). I had been using CakePHP so far and now planning to switch to Drupal.

I am using Drupal's Form API to create a form page.I have almost completed 'Create' operation. I have a few of questions before I go too far.

1. Should this form be a Drupal's content/node type?
2. Can I reuse the 'Create' source for 'Update' operation? (like in
   CakePHP)?
3. How does the permissions work with this kind of module?

PS: My form is highly customized so I am not up for using CCK/Views. 
And, I am also very confused after doing some CakePHP. I keep relating CakePHP and Drupal. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) are nice thing to start:

1. If you form don't work with nodes, it willn't. Otherwise investigate *node_example* and *nodeapi_examples*.
2. Yes, you should send argument via menu definition, that identify ID and load it from DB. After this assign loaded values to [#default_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#default_value). So http://site.com/YOURFORMPATH will used for creation, http://site.com/YOURFORMPATH/ID for updating/deleting.
3. See *menu_example* how menu defined with permissions. and define for your "YOURFORMPATH" menu item.